What is the purpose of the word in an index signature?
Given the type below, what is the purpose of the word key?
type Foo = {
    [key: string]: string;
};

Isn't the below exactly the same as above?
type Foo = {
    [thisSeemsToBeCompletelyUseless: string]: string;
};

Is its only purpose to provide context? Why doesn't something like this work?
type Foo = {
    [string]: string;
};

// OR

type Foo = {
    [:string]: string;
};

I have read the documentation and I have yet to find any mention of the purpose of the word.

It's a dummy identifier representing a key variable. So, if you have a variable x of type string, then {[x]: 123} is of type {[x: string]: 123}. It serves only syntactic purpose, and the exact identifier you use is, as you note, completely arbitrary and doesn't change assignability. The same can be said for dummy parameter names in function types ((x: string) => void and (z: string) => void are the same) or labels in tuples ([a: number] and [b: number] are the same). I'm not sure if there's an official doc source that isn't an outdated spec. I'll look.

Hmm, even the index signature section of the outdated spec doesn't explicitly mention that in the text.  It's a BindingIdentifier and is referred to nowhere else (which implies it doesn't matter) but it isn't clear. Maybe there is no good doc for it.
